# How to pass and ID and call a Laravel 5.4 method in controller using JavaScript, jQuery or AJAX?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

In my blade view..

```
<a href="#" id="plus"  onclick="incrementValue()" value="{{$di->did}}">
   <i class="material-icons"value="{{$di['did']}}" id="inc" style="color:#30BB6D">add_circle</i>
   </a>
```

My script..

```
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;


    document.getElementById('number').value = value;



}
```

What i want when this button/icon is click it will proceed to a route

```
Route::get('addToCart/{id}', 'HomeController@addToCart')->name('dish.addtocart');
```

My method in the controller

```
    public function addToCart(Request $request, $id){
        if(Request::ajax()){
        $dish=Dish::where('did', $id)->get();
        foreach($dish as $d){
            $price = $d->sellingPrice;
        }

        $oldCart=Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart= new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->addCart($dish, $id, $price);
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);



        return redirect()->route('user.index');
    }

}
```

and will also increment the quantity 
I hope i can do this without refreshing the page

Could someone help me in passing the id and calling the method in the controller?

Comment: Why your route is get method?

Comment: It should be post?

Comment: When i changed it to post method is it not working

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your incrementValue()

```
$http.post("Your_post_url", which_data_you_want_to_pass)
    .success(function(response){  
       //after post success...
});
```